# Transforming a function's return type from AnyPushliser<ReturnObj, error> to ReturnObj in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift Combine and re-writing the code for my functionality in Swift Combine where the function is returning `AnyPublisher<Person, Error>`.

```
public func newPublisherFunction() -> AnyPublisher<Person, Error> {
   .....
}
```

However, the callers of my code are still on Obj-C (even Swift too but not using Combine) and the function which they are invoking, in my code presently, returns a direct object type `Person` as shown below

```
// this is the function being used by different callers
public func existingFunction() -> Person {
   ....
}
```

Is there a way possible to create a bridging function which can take value (of type `Person`) emitted by `someFunction1()` and just return that value.

Specifically asking, I want to implement something like below

```
public func newPublisherFunction() -> AnyPublisher<Person, Error> {
   .....
}

func bridgingFunction() -> Person {
   var person: Person

   // logic to consume value from newPublisherFunction()
   // and assign it to 'person'

   return person
}

public func existingFunction() -> Person {
   return self.bridgingFunction()
}
```

Comment: You could call `sink` on the publisher to receive and return the value. But this raises another question: What should happen to the `Error`?

Comment: Error case is not a problem for now, in this situation. That I will handle. One problem is that while we start to consume the value from the Publisher, it becomes an async process. So before the value is sinked, `return` statement gets executed, whereas the value from Publisher is getting sinked afterwards.

I will still try out your solution and check if its working fine.